# Number of vertices ignored by glDrawElements() in libGDX

Tags: libgdx, opengl-es-2.0

I'm attempting to use libGDX to port an Android game which uses opengl es 2.0. Under libGDX the glDrawElements() routine seems to be broken on the PC, but works on Android. On the PC version the second parameter (number of vertices) gets ignored. When I comment the line using mFaceIndicesData.length and use 3 verts (1 face triangle), it still draws all faces on PC version, but only one face on Android version, as shown in images of each.

Yes I know libGDX is supposed to be used with libGDX calls, so please don't comment on that. I have an entire game engine and it is pretty complex. I prefer having control over the engine instead of figuring out some other engine, and I'm pretty sure it can do some things not supported under libGDX. Anyway I don't want to start all over from scratch. I'm just looking for a good way to port from Android to PC/IOS and libGDX seems like it might be a good choice.

[image: Android with only 1 triangle drawn]

[image: Desktop launch (PC) draws all triangle no matter how many verts are specified]

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
...
    @Override
    public void create() {
    GLES20 = Gdx.gl20;
...

// Works on PC and Android
GLES20.glDrawElements(GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, mFaceIndicesData.length, GL20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndices);

// Only works on Android. Not PC.
//GLES20.glDrawElements(GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndices);
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted the problem on the libgdx issues site. It has been confirmed as a bug and they are in the process of fixing it.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/6618